# Problema al mostrar AlertDialog en Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Actualmente tengo un problema al querer mostrar un AlertDialog en Flutter pero solo cuando se encuentra dentro de un bloque de respuesta en un método, en este caso después de la llamada a un servicio Rest.

El método es: mostrarAlertSimple.

En el ejemplo lo intente poniendo el await y sin el await...

La invocación es la siguiente:

```
 Function miServicioRest(BuildContext context){
if(obj != null){     
final api = Provider.of<RestClient>(context, listen: false);

String param1 = ***;
int param2 = ***;

api.miServicioRest(param1, param2, obj.idObj).then((it) async {

  if (it == null) {
             // ESTE LLAMADO NO MUESTRA EL ALERT DIALOG
    await mostrarAlertSimple(context, '', SERV_MSJ_MAL);         
  }else if(!(it.statusCode == 1)){

     // ESTE LLAMADO NO MUESTRA EL ALERT DIALOG
      await mostrarAlertSimple(context, '', it?.message ?? SERV_MSJ_VACIO);         

  }           
  else {
    // Todo OK..

    await mostrarAlertWithEvent(context, 'Solicitud', it?.message ?? SERV_MSJ_VACIO, (context){
        Navigator.pop(context);
    });

  }

}).catchError((Object obj) async {
  print('Error ...');
  // non-200 error goes here.
  switch (obj.runtimeType) {
    case DioError:
      // Here's the sample to get the failed response error code and message
      final res = (obj as DioError).response;                    
      print("Got error : ${res.statusCode} -> ${res.statusMessage}");
      Map datos = (res.data as Map);
      await mostrarAlertSimple(context, 'Error', datos['message']);
      break;
    default:
  }            

});

}    
 }
```

El código de mis alert los tengo en un Mixin.

```
  class MixinPage { 

   mostrarAlertSimple(BuildContext context, String titulo,String mensaje){
      showDialog(
       context: context,
       barrierDismissible: true,
       builder: (context){
         return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(titulo),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(mensaje),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[

          FlatButton(             
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();

              }
            )
           ],
        );  
         }
       );
    }


   mostrarAlertWithEvent(BuildContext context, String titulo,String mensaje, Function e){
       showDialog(
       context: context,
       barrierDismissible: true,
       builder: (context){
       return AlertDialog(
        title: Text(titulo),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)),
        content: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(mensaje),
          ],
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[

          FlatButton(             
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.of(context).pop();
              e();
            }
          )
        ],
         );  
        }
       );
   }

 }
```

Al mostrar el dialog lanza un error y se va al catch de DIoError , imprimiendo el objeto completo muestra lo siguiente:

Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

Comment: tienes algún error? que muestra en pantalla? por que flujo va? entra a la condición if (it == null) { ?   o  }else if(!(it.statusCode == 1)){ ?   si no entra entonces es un problema de tu servicio  miServicioRest

Comment: Ya agregue el mensaje que sale en error, el servicio esta bien, sin embargo esa excepcion no siempre sale :/, por ejemplo el día de ayer ya funcionaba agregando los await, mostraba los alert pero en este momento ya no funciona :/

Comment: pero entra a las condiciones o no? si no entra ,pues no mostrará los dialogs

Comment: Si, el problema no es el servicio, yo controlo las respuestas, y en todo caso todas las condiciones de los if-else tienen una llamada para mostrar un mensaje con el alert, a lo que me refiero es que no importa el camino de los IF-ELSE , cualquier bloque en el que llegue tiene una llamada a los alert.

Comment: ese error es porq el context que usas para mostrar los alerts ya no se encuentra en el arbol de widgets, probablemente porque tu pantalla fue cerrada

Comment: Si, cambie el context y lo puse como variable global en el Page y lo asigno al inicio del build,  al enviarlo de esa manera ya se muestra al parecer.

Comment: no te recomendaría manejar variables globales

Comment: ¿y de qué otra manera lo manejarias para mantener la referencia?

Comment: tendría q ver tu código completo para ver como lo estás manejando y hacer la corrección